# Java, get an Objects elements to Map

Tags: java, google-cloud-firestore

I get an object from FireStore, `Object obj = document.toObject(Object.class);` that has titles and bodys (see picture), I want to pass these data into a **Map**:
 `Map<String, Object>`

(obj looks like:

```
0  
  key="body"  
  value="somevalue"  
1  
  key="title"  
  value="somevalue"
```

if you cant see the pic.)
But this data **can be anything**, this is why I dont use a special class for it. because there can't be a class, the users can put literally anything there.
So I would like to know how can I put these into a map as keys and bodys

```
myMap.put(obj.???, obj.???)
```

[the data in debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VUGj.jpg)

Comment: I'm not familiar with FireStore, but what happens if you use `toObject(Map.class)`?

Comment: maybe `Map<String, String> obj = (HashMap<String, String>) document.toObject(Object.class);`

Comment: @chrylis java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not deserialize object. Class java.util.Map has generic type parameters, please use GenericTypeIndicator instead

Comment: That error message tells you what to do--apparently there's a `GenericTypeIndicator` version that you should use.

Comment: @YCF_L that did the trick

Comment: nice I post it as an answer, it can be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Just cast your `obj` to the correct type, so from the picture `document.toObject(Object.class)` return a `HashMap` of String key and value, in this case just use :

```
Map<String, String> obj = (HashMap) document.toObject(Object.class);
```